# Problem Moving Public Folder When Using Laravel Mix: I Get 404 Error

Tags: php, laravel, mixins, laravel-mix

When running a project using Laravel Mix, I get a 404 and cannot access the pages.
I did composer install
I didn't create the project, it had a structure like this before.

```
main
-core
  -app
  -routes
  -...
-index.php
-assets
```

I think they moved the public folder to a higher folder, so I created the public folder again and moved it there.
require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; I made the paths as follows, then when I do php artisan serve it works but I get 404 and I can't access any page.

I can't reach the example route, it gives 404

```
    Route::get('/test', function () {
    return "test route!";
});
```

I went to console

```
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Thu Feb 29 16:22:53 2024] PHP 7.4.33 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Thu Feb 29 16:23:00 2024] 127.0.0.1:49296 Accepted
[Thu Feb 29 16:23:01 2024] 127.0.0.1:49296 Closing
```

package.json

```
 {
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
            "dev": "npm run development",
            "development": "mix",
            "watch": "mix watch",
            "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
            "hot": "mix watch --hot",
            "prod": "npm run production",
            "production": "mix --production"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "axios": "^0.21",
            "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
            "lodash": "^4.17.19",
            "postcss": "^8.1.14"
        }
    }
```

It works but I get 404 and I can't access the page.

Comment: I would suggest that, with that directory structure, this is not a Laravel app. You have also tagged the question with [tag:codeigniter]?

Answer (score 0):

I entered the install index.php in the directory as localhost/xxx/install/index.php and installed it and it was solved.